# Adding a new column,splitting a column value in two then insert a part of the value in the new column

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I have a table with a column 'Name', like the following:

```
    Name
Michael Jackson
Chester Bennington
Mike Shinoda
```

I want to split the 'Name' values in FirstName and LastName,blike this:

```
LastName          FirstName
Jackson          Michael
Bennington       Chester
Shinoda          Mike
```

And also I need to create new columns and add those values, all in a single query if its possible.
So as a review, I have Name, I need to create LastName, FirstName columns, split the Name values after the first blank space,the value before the blank space will go into LastName and the values after the blank space will go into FirstName. This is what I have tried so far:

```
ALTER TABLE `data` ADD `FirstName` VARCHAR(30),ADD `LastName` VARCHAR(30)  
INSERT INTO `data`(`LastName`,`FirstName`) VALUES ('...','...')
```

Help please..

Comment: That would be odd if it could be done all in one statement. I think you need to do the `ALTER TABLE` first, followed by an `UPDATE` statement. One question I would have is whether the existing names are guaranteed to be first name + space + last name, or whether there might be a middle initial (or middle name) or a first or last name containing a space (e.g., 'von Hildebrand').

Comment: you can use single transaction,but not in single query

Comment: @DavidFaber , the existing names are exactly like in the question,just separated by a blank space.And if it's possible i would like the first part of the name to be the LastName and the second part to be the FirstName.(example: Jackson Michael)

Comment: @PetruLebada, what do you mean by `if it's possible`? What do the data currently look like? Is the first name first in the `Name` column or last? If you're wondering whether the column order matters, it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidFaber , in my Name column, the LastName is first And the FirstName is Second,so i can use this to extract the FirstName and move it to a different column,something like moving the string before blank space to a column,and the string after the blank space to another string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE data SET FirstName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1), LastName = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 2),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1)) + 1)
```

**EDIT**

As David Faber stated, one can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1)` for updating the `LastName` column.

Comment: I think for `LastName` one might do `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1)`

Comment: @DavidFaber That's even better, man. I've updated the answer, thank you.

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1)` will return `FirstName` if no `LastName` exists - no space will goback to the start of the string. The original `SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 2),  LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1)) + 1)` will return empty string which is more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You might try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `data` ADD `FirstName` VARCHAR(30)
                 , ADD `LastName` VARCHAR(30);

UPDATE `data`
   SET `FirstName` = SUBSTR( `Name`, 1, INSTR(`Name`, ' ') - 1 )
     , `LastName` = SUBSTR( `Name`, INSTR(`Name`, ' ') + 1, LENGTH(`Name`) - INSTR(`Name`, ' ') )
 WHERE `Name` LIKE '% %';
```

I added the `WHERE` clause with `LIKE` operator to the update statement; otherwise it could fail if `Name` has any values without spaces since `INSTR()` will return 0 for these.

Alternately, instead of `SUBSTR()` you might use `LEFT()` and RIGHT()`:

```
UPDATE `data`
   SET `FirstName` = LEFT( `Name`, INSTR(`Name`, ' ') - 1 )
     , `LastName` = RIGHT( `Name`, LENGTH(`Name`) - INSTR(`Name`, ' ') )
 WHERE `Name` LIKE '% %';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

INSTR shows error, so used POSITION. I am trying to split the columns at character '/':

```
UPDATE pincode
   SET latitude = LEFT( coordinates, POSITION('/' IN coordinates) - 1 )
     , longitude = RIGHT( coordinates, LENGTH(coordinates) - POSITION('/' IN coordinates) )
 WHERE coordinates LIKE '%/%';
```

Answer (score -1):

This is your table. You use it how you want.
Try this

```
select * from
(
select SUBSTRING ( name ,(select CHARINDEX(' ',name, 0) from table1)+1 , (select LEN(name) from table1)-(select CHARINDEX(' ',name, 0) from table1)-1) as lastname,
SUBSTRING ( name ,0 , (select LEN(name) from table1)-(select CHARINDEX(' ',name, 0) from table1)) as firstname
from table1;
)
```

Comment: Is `CHARINDEX()` even a function in MySQL?

Comment: it is in mssql. in mysql you should use SUBSTRING_INDEX().

Comment: One might use `INSTR()` too, or `POSITION()` (which is standard SQL).